# Check if empty Cart in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a global way to check in any .tpl file without making modifications to the controllers and views to see if the basket is empty. This does not always work:

```
$cartItems = $this->cart->countProducts();
if ($cartItems < 0) {
    print "Your cart is empty"
}
```

It appears that it works when logged in and sometimes as a guest?

Comment: Does the code you posted work *sometimes*? Should it not be $cartItems === 0?

Comment: How can there be less than zero items?

Comment: @knittl just seen that now! My mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much better sollution is just to call

```
if ( ! $this->cart->hasProducts()) {
    print "Your cart is empty";
}
```

It is much quicker and refers directly to a product count within a cart.

The method `$this->cart->countProducts()` does not count the products within a cart, but calculates the **total product pieces count** within a cart. So it **loads all the products** in a cart and **in a loop** adds each product's quantity. Therefore it is slower - not much, You might even not register the difference - but yet it is a little slower (the more products in a cart the more slower it is because of the loop).

Comment: I have updated my answer as this is correct despite shadyyx being a nob head.

Answer (score -1):

```
$cart_contents = $this->cart->countProducts();
if ($cart_contents === 0) {
    print "Your cart is empty"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, credit should ideally go to knittl and Gibbs but since your knew I will ignore the hijack.